# Android App is crashing on some devices after 64bit support

Tags: android, crash, 64-bit

We have added the 64 Bit support by,

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

but the app is crashing on some devices with following

```
logFatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 4 in tid 24161 (JavaBridge)
 Build fingerprint: 'motorola/cedric_amzin/cedric:7.0/NPP25.137-33/31:user/release-keys'
 Revision: 'p500'
 ABI: 'arm'
 pid: 22690, tid: 24161, name: JavaBridge  >>> com.manash.purplle <<<
signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 4 (TRAP_HWBKPT), fault addr 0x9e7f01b6


backtrace:
  #00 pc 005a4106  /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk (offset 0x1f23000)
  #01 pc 005a4019  /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk (offset 0x1f23000)
```

Comment: Devnavar ,can you please share with us, how you support 64 bit I have added `ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'` , but I can't upload my app bundle to Google Play, it said I should support 64bit

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: Are you using Juspay SDK ?